# Java: HashMap behaving in an unexpected manner

Tags: java, hashmap

So I have this hashmap with key as String and holds values as an integer array.

```
HashMap<String, Integer[]> h = new HashMap<String, Integer[]>();
h.put("PID", new Integer[] {3, 5});
```

I was trying `int` first, but then I read somewhere that primitive types can't be used in generics.

So, Eclipse says

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
- Syntax error on tokens, ConstructorHeaderName expected 
 instead
- Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
```

for the second line. First line is fine for it.

Comment: True, primitive types can't be used (`int`), but arrays of primitives are allowed because any array is also an object. Therefore `int[]` is a valid type and you can avoid boxing it.

Comment: You can `int[]` instead of `Integer[]` - in java the arrays are classes, so there is no problem to use array of primitives with generics

Comment: Yes, I did use `int[]` as well. But it says the same error for the second line even then.

Comment: did you initialize the hashmap outside of function or constructor?

Comment: Yes, I have initialized it above `main()` globally for the class.

Comment: No you can not do that. you can not insert or get outside of any function.

Comment: @javaseeker, I moved the `put` line inside `main()` and it says `The method put(String, int[]) in the type HashMap<String,int[]> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Integer[])`

Comment: because `int[]` is not the same as `Integer[]` - either change your map to `<String, Integer[]>` or use `int[]`

Comment: The code you posted is fine in the right context.  There is nothing wrong with the individual statements.  Please post as much surrounding code as you can.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev He says he gets the same error when he used int[] so it must e something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement must be executed inside of any function or constructor. you can not insert, delete or update in global space.

This is a statement, you can't write statement at the place you are trying to do

> h.put("PID", new Integer[] {3, 5});

Again you can not execute below statement because int[] is a primitive array and Integer[] is a arary of Integer Object. you have declared key,value == String,Integer[] so you can not insert int[] array

> h.put("PID", new int[] {3, 5});

Again java Hashmap does not support primitive data type. you must have to use Object as key or value of Hashamp.

Comment: Thanks. I got the fix now somehow. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: How do I get the integers now, for some key value?

Comment: h.get(Object key) or you can iterate.

Comment: int[] nums = h.get("PID");
// nums[0] is 3, nums[1] is 5

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        HashMap<String, int[]> h = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
        h.put("PID", new int[] {3, 5});


        System.out.println(h.get("PID")[0]); //prints "3"
        System.out.println(h.get("PID")[1]); //prints "5"
     }
}
```